# Combine array values based on first element of array using ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I have the following code:

```
arr = [["a",1],["a",2],["b",1],["b",2]]
```

I want to merge the array that should like

```
arr1 = [["a",1,2],["b",1,2]]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
arr = [["a",1],["a",2],["b",1],["b",2]]
arr.group_by(&:first).map{ |key, value|
  [key, *value.map(&:last)]
}
# => [["a", 1, 2], ["b", 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Or less noisy: `arr.group_by(&:first).map { |k, vs| [ k, *vs.map(&:last) ] }`.

Comment: @muistooshort, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to you.

Comment: @falsetru it is not exactly working out for my array
"a = [["Sep 08, 2014", "1"], ["Sep 08, 2014", "2"], ["Sep 15, 2014", "2"], ["Sep 15,2014", "2"]]
a.group_by(&:first).map{ |key, value|
  [key, *value.map(&:last)]
}
Output:
###### [["Sep 08, 2014", "1", "2"], ["Sep 15, 2014", "2"], ["Sep 15,2014", "2"]]
"

Comment: @SaiVardhan, The date in the last element `["Sep 15,2014", "2"]`, has no space between day and year unlike other elements.